# Raspberry Pi USB Devices

Tags: usb, rfid

I have two USB RFID. They are connected to Raspberry Pi and sends data to pi. How can I know which one is sending data?

Note: Running only one RFID at the same time.

Comment: Don't they have unique id numbers?

Comment: Most USB peripherals don't have serial numbers, though there are exceptions.  At some level of the USB stack Linux probably knows which physical port on the hub carries which logical device, but obtaining that may be tricky.  I know it has been discussed on one of the SE sites (SO, EESE, Unix) before, so you could search that as well as troll through the information exposed by the USB stack.